# How to call entity manager class in subscriber using symfony 2.3?

Tags: symfony

I want to call repository class function in Event Subscriber. There are 3 tables

---

*Tables* :

---

```
country : id, name, abbr, is_active
city : id, cityname, is_active
countrycity : id,countryid, cityid.
```

---

I should provide manage city in admin panel where admin can add their own city for that country.

For an application I have create a commonBundle in which all common entities reside which will use in both admin panel & frontend.

---

Form : D:\wamp\www\cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType.php

---

```
namespace Cl\CommonBundle\Form;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
    class CityType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                    ->add("country", "entity", array("class" => "ClCommonBundle:Country", "property" => "countryname", "empty_value" => "-- Select Country --", "required" => false, "constraints" => new Constraints\NotBlank(array("message" => "Country should not be empty"))))
                    ->add("cityname", "text", array("label" => "Name", "required" => false))
                    ->add("isactive", "checkbox", array("required" => false, "label" => "Is active?", "mapped" => true))

            //->add('createdat')
            //->add('updatedat')
            ;
            $builder->addEventSubscriber(new EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber());

            /* $builder->addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function(FormInterface $form) {
              $country = $form->get("country")->getData();
              if (!$country) {
              $form['country']->addError(new FormError("Country should not be emtpy"));
              }
              }
              )); */
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
         */
        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                // "data_class" => "Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\City",
                "csrf_token" => true,
                "csrf_token_name" => "_token",
                "method" => "POST",
                // to generate unique key token per form
                "intention" => "city",
                "country" => true,
                "mapped" => false,
                'allowExtraFields' => true
                    // validation group
                    //"validation_groups" => false,
            ));
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'Cl_commonbundle_city';
        }

    }
```

---

I create function of event listner to call an error if the cityname is already exist for that country.

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber());
    The code of event listiner is following.
```

---

EventListner : D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php

---

```
namespace Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry;

class ValidateCountryCitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $em;
    /**
     * @param EntityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'postSubmit'];
    }
    public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $country = $event->getForm()->getData()->country->getId();
        $cityname = $data->getCityname();
        $this->em->getRepository("CommonBundle:CountryCity")->validateCountryCity($country, $city);
        //$form->addError(new FormError("City is already exists for this country"));
    }
}
```

---

Service create in D:\wamp\www\Cl\app\config\config.yml

---

```
doctrine.listner:
class: Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber
arguments:
    - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

---

:: Error ::

---

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

```
1/1 ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType.php on line 27 and defined in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php line 20
in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php line 20
at ErrorHandler->handle('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType.php on line 27 and defined', 'D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php', '20', array()) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php line 20
at ValidateCountryCitySubscriber->__construct() in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType.php line 27
at CityType->buildForm(object(FormBuilder), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'attr' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'data_class' => 'Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\City', 'empty_data' => object(Closure), 'trim' => true, 'required' => true, 'read_only' => false, 'max_length' => null, 'pattern' => null, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => false, 'by_reference' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true, 'label_attr' => array(), 'virtual' => null, 'inherit_data' => false, 'compound' => true, 'method' => 'POST', 'validation_groups' => null, 'error_mapping' => array(), 'constraints' => array(), 'cascade_validation' => false, 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_provider' => object(SessionCsrfProvider), 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'intention' => 'city', 'csrf_token' => true, 'csrf_token_name' => '_token', 'country' => true, 'allowExtraFields' => true, 'action' => '/Cl/web/app_dev.php/admin/city/insert', 'data' => object(City))) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType.php line 158
at ResolvedFormType->buildForm(object(FormBuilder), array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'attr' => array(), 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'data_class' => 'Cl\CommonBundle\Entity\City', 'empty_data' => object(Closure), 'trim' => true, 'required' => true, 'read_only' => false, 'max_length' => null, 'pattern' => null, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => false, 'by_reference' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true, 'label_attr' => array(), 'virtual' => null, 'inherit_data' => false, 'compound' => true, 'method' => 'POST', 'validation_groups' => null, 'error_mapping' => array(), 'constraints' => array(), 'cascade_validation' => false, 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_provider' => object(SessionCsrfProvider), 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'intention' => 'city', 'csrf_token' => true, 'csrf_token_name' => '_token', 'country' => true, 'allowExtraFields' => true, 'action' => '/Cl/web/app_dev.php/admin/city/insert', 'data' => object(City))) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType.php line 117
at ResolvedFormType->createBuilder(object(FormFactory), 'Cl_commonbundle_city', array('action' => '/Cl/web/app_dev.php/admin/city/insert', 'data' => object(City))) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php line 87
at FormFactory->createNamedBuilder('Cl_commonbundle_city', object(CityType), object(City), array('action' => '/Cl/web/app_dev.php/admin/city/insert')) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php line 67
at FormFactory->createBuilder(object(CityType), object(City), array('action' => '/Cl/web/app_dev.php/admin/city/insert')) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php line 39
at FormFactory->create(object(CityType), object(City), array('action' => '/Cl/web/app_dev.php/admin/city/insert')) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 163
at Controller->createForm(object(CityType), object(City), array('action' => '/Cl/web/app_dev.php/admin/city/insert')) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\AdminBundle\Controller\CityController.php line 19
at CityController->__processForm(array('entity' => object(City), 'path' => '_admin_city_insert', 'button_label' => 'Add')) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\AdminBundle\Controller\CityController.php line 38
at CityController->addAction(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CityController), 'addAction'), array(object(Request))) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2889
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in D:\wamp\www\Cl\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2863
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2992
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2272
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in D:\wamp\www\Cl\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify from which namespace EntityManager is.

So just add `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;` in your subscriber:

```
namespace Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager; // this was lacking

class ValidateCountryCitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I see now where the problem is.

You created the subscriber as a service but in type class you don't use it as a service, but instead you created new object by yourself. This is a mistake, you should use container for managaing dependencies. Try the following way:

1. Define `CityType` as a service
2. Inject subscriber into `CityType` and use this injected object

**EDIT 2:**

The problem is because of this line:

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber());
```

You created new subscriber object but never passed EntityManager dependency. But you already have your subscriber defined as a service: `doctrine.listner` . So, the only thing you have to do is to inject it inside `CityType` class.

In order to do that, you need define `CityType` as a service:

```
form.type.city:
    class: Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType
    arguments: [ @doctrine.listner ]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: city_type }
```

Of course you need to modify `CityType` a little (create constructor where you inject your `ValidateCountryCitySubscriber` class and `$doctrineListener` property):

```
protected $doctrineListener

public function __construct(ValidateCountryCitySubscriber $doctrineListener)
{
    $this->doctrineListener = $doctrineListener;
}
```

And then inside the type class you add the subscriber in that way:

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber($this->doctrineListener);
```

Comment: Thanks Cyprian sorry for bad formatting because I am new for stackoverflow edit so sometime mashup formatting of code.

Comment: I have tried same before this but stilL I am getting error ::

Comment: ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType.php on line 27 and defined in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php line 20

Comment: You have problem with building subscriber directly - please see edited answer

Comment: I am not understand your way described in edited comment

Comment: doctrine.listner:
        class: Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber
        tags: 
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

Comment: 1/1 ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\wamp\www\collegelife\src\Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\CityType.php on line 27 and defined in D:\wamp\www\collegelife\src\Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php line 20

Comment: Edited my answer. I can't explain in more clear way :)

Comment: Thanks It generates an error of circular doctrine reference.

Comment: Your answer is so much clear but I got still error yar

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

1 -  As [Cyprian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023464/cyprian) said, you should let `ValidateCountryCitySubscriber` know where to find `EntityManager`

so `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` have to be included into your use definitions into `ValidateCountryCitySubscriber` class

<strike>2 - You should modify your `config.yml` into</strike>

```
doctrine.listner:
    class: Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

Also your syntax seems to be fine

### Edit

Problem is also into your `FormType`: you shouldn't instatiate direclty a service (and your `ValidateCountryCitySubscriber` is).
So you can modify your `config.yml` that way

```
yourbundle.citytype:
    class: Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType
    arguments: [ @doctrine.listner ]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: Cl_commonbundle_city }
```

You are injecting your `doctrine.listner` service into the form (that now is a service too).

Than modify `CityType`

```
use Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php;
class CityType extends AbstractType
{
    private $vccs; //validate country city subscriber

    public function __construct(ValidateCountryCitySubscriber $validate_country_city_sub)
    {
        $this->vccs = $validate_country_city_sub;
    }  

    [...]

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        [...]
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->vccs);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks don, I have followed all way, I struck from a day and half, I still got and error::   ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\CityType.php on line 27 and defined in D:\wamp\www\Cl\src\Cl\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber.php line 20

Comment: @DonCallisto - the way Dipak used to pass argument to the service is also correct

Comment: @Cyprian: I really didn't know. Thanks :)

Comment: @Dipakchavda: see my update. maybe you should adjust with namespace or correct file location :)

Comment: Yes Don, I have followed same way event I tried other way also but still I am not able to find solution.. The error said that entitymanger must be and instance of citytype and described in ValidateCountryCitySubscrib‌​er

Comment: @Dipakchavda: I've impression that you're messing up the things. Starting from my answer or Cyprian one you should be able to overtake the issue

Comment: @DOn: There is nothing about mess up. I have followed same.

Comment: @Don : I am not understand Cyprian edited answer. Can you also explain?

Comment: @Dipakchavda: he's saying the same as me. please if you want more help please provide error message as I may miss something