# symfony 2.3 call entitymanager class in subscriber issue is still not resolved

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The issue is follow my previous question :
[Please click on this to know more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906427/how-to-call-entity-manager-class-in-subscriber-using-symfony-2-3)

I am still not able to access doctrine repository class in subscriber class. 
I have already followed steps suggested by Cyprian, DonCallisto.

**Error**

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\CityType::__construct() must be an instance of Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber, none given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php on line 19 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/CommonBundle/Form/CityType.php line 17

in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/CommonBundle/Form/CityType.php line 17
at ErrorHandler->handle('4096', 'Argument 1 passed to Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\CityType::__construct() must be an instance of Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber, none given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php on line 19 and defined', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/CommonBundle/Form/CityType.php', '17', array()) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/CommonBundle/Form/CityType.php line 17
at CityType->__construct() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php line 19
at CityController->__processForm(array('entity' => object(City), 'path' => '_admin_city_insert', 'button_label' => 'Add')) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/src/Collegelife/AdminBundle/Controller/CityController.php line 53
at CityController->insertAction(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CityController), 'insertAction'), array(object(Request))) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2889
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2863
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2992
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2272
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

**My Present Code :**

**Citytype.php**

```
<?php namespace Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form;
use Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
class CityType extends AbstractType
{
// Validate CountryCity Subscriber

protected $validateCountryCitySubscriber;

public function __construct(ValidateCountryCitySubscriber $validateCountryCitySubscriber){
    $this->validateCountryCitySubscriber = $validateCountryCitySubscriber;  
}


/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add("country", "entity", array("class" => "CollegelifeCommonBundle:Country", "property" => "countryname", "empty_value" => "-- Select Country --", "required" => false, "constraints" => new Constraints\NotBlank(array("message" => "Country should not be empty"))))
    ->add("cityname", "text", array("label" => "Name", "required" => false))
    ->add("isactive", "checkbox", array("required" => false, "label" => "Is active?", "mapped" => true))

    //->add('createdat')
    //->add('updatedat')
    ;
    $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->validateCountryCitySubscriber);

    //$builder->addEventSubscriber(new EventListner\ValidateCountryCitySubscriber());

    /* $builder->addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function(FormInterface $form) {
     $country = $form->get("country")->getData();
            if (!$country) {
            $form['country']->addError(new FormError("Country should not be emtpy"));
            }
            }
    )); */
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            // "data_class" => "Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\City",
            "csrf_token" => true,
            "csrf_token_name" => "_token",
            "method" => "POST",
            // to generate unique key token per form
            "intention" => "city",
            "country" => true,
            "mapped" => false,
            'allowExtraFields' => true
            // validation group
            //"validation_groups" => false,
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'collegelife_commonbundle_city';
}
}?>
```

**validateCountryCitySubscriber.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry;

class ValidateCountryCitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'postSubmit');
}

public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $country = $event->getForm()->getData()->country->getId();
    $cityname = $data->getCityname();
    $this->em->getRepository("CommonBundle:CountryCity")->validateCountryCity($country, $city);     
    exit();
    //$form->addError(new FormError("City is already exists for this country"));
}
}?>
```

**validateCountryCitySubscriber.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\EventListner;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry;

class ValidateCountryCitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'postSubmit');
}

public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $country = $event->getForm()->getData()->country->getId();
    $cityname = $data->getCityname();
    //$this->em->getRepository("CommonBundle:CountryCity")->validateCountryCity($country, $city);
    //var_dump($data);
    //        echo "Query:" . $this->er->createQueryBuilder()->select("cc.id")
    //                ->from("CountryCity", "cc")
    //                ->join("cc", "City", "ci", "cc.cityid = ci.id")
    //                ->getQuery();
    exit();
    //$form->addError(new FormError("City is already exists for this country"));
}
}?>
```

**CityController.php**

```
<?php namespace Collegelife\AdminBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\CountryType;
use Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\CityType;
use Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\Country;
use Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\CountryCity;
use Collegelife\CommonBundle\Entity\City;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class CityController extends Controller
{
private function __processForm($params)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CityType(), $params["entity"], array("action" => $this->generateUrl($params["path"])));
    if ($params['button_label'] == "Update") {
        $form->add("cid", "hidden");
    }
    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array("label" => $params['button_label'], "attr" => array("class" => "btn btn-success")));
    return $form;
}

public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    if (false === $this->get("security.context")->isGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Unable access this page");
    }
    $entity = new City();
    $params = array(
            "entity" => $entity,
            "path" => "_admin_city_insert",
            "button_label" => "Add"
    );
    $addForm = $this->__processForm($params);
    return $this->render("CollegelifeAdminBundle:City:add.html.twig", array("form" => $addForm->createView(), "header_label" => "Add"));
}

public function insertAction(Request $request)
{
    if (false === $this->get("security.context")->isGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Unable access this page");
    }
    $entity = new City();
    $params = array(
            "entity" => $entity,
            "path" => "_admin_city_insert",
            "button_label" => "Add"
    );
    $addForm = $this->__processForm($params);
    $addForm->handleRequest($request);
    $req = $request->request->get("collegelife_commonbundle_city");
    if ($addForm->isValid() && $addForm->get("submit")->isClicked()) {
        $req = $request->request->get("collegelife_commonbundle_city");

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($entity);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        //$this->get("session")->getFlashBag()->add("message", "City add successfully");
        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("_admin_country_list"));
    }
    return $this->render("CollegelifeAdminBundle:City:add.html.twig", array("form" => $addForm->createView(), "header_label" => "Add"));
}

public function listAction()
{
    if (false === $this->get("security.context")->isGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Unable access this page");
    }
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("CollegelifeCommonBundle:CountryCity")->findAll();
    return $this->render("CollegelifeAdminBundle:City:list.html.twig", array("entity" => $entity));
}
}?>
```

**services.yml**

```
parameters:
     collegelife_common_citytype_form.class: Collegelife\CommonBundle\Form\CityType

services:
collegelife_validate_countrycity_subscriber:
    class: %collegelife_common_citytype_form.class%
    arguments: ["@doctrine.listner"]
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: Colleglife_commonbundle_citytype }
```

Comment: You have lots and lots of issues.  I'm afraid that you are just going to have to spend some time reading the manual and learn how things fit together.  Maybe start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service but I'd really suggest you go through the forms chapter and work the examples.

Comment: Thanks Dear Cerad for your response, but I have already go through for the same before 2-3 times.

Comment: I think this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906427/how-to-call-entity-manager-class-in-subscriber-using-symfony-2-3

Comment: It's my question post ketan